# SharePoint GetListItems() from library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Good Morning

I have SharePoint page and library which holds some files.

This files are displayed there.

Is there good way to use WebServices to get the all items from this library using VBS?

Which webService methood would be the best for that.

Thanks

Comment: I need this to get all library items content.

Lets say we have library and some files inside of this.

Each of this files has status like "New, Printed, Sent"

So I would like to update this statuses later.

Comment: What is the purpose of using VBS

Comment: Looking on the solution which we are using, we have to use VBS for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharePoint REST API. You will find complete documentation for rest api over here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Try:

```
Dim a As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

a.Open "GET", url, False
```

Be sure to add reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0"

Comment: Is it works also inside Visual Basic Script? Or only inside Visual Basic

Comment: It will also work in VBS

Comment: Thanks. I am allso curious, is it right that I need to be Site Collection Administrator to perform some requests?

Comment: It is not require to be Site Collection Admin but you should have permission to read permission to fetch list

Comment: Ok. Which web service can be used to fetch the list of files inside Library? Previously I was using list (status list) and now I need to get current files from library folder. Could You please tell me which web service can be used?

Comment: https://<SharePointURL>/_api/web/lists('<listname>')/items

Comment: remove <> from while putting your real values

Comment: Ok so if I want to get library files then I will use List webservices also? Thanks :)

Comment: https://<SharePointURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<libraryName>')?$select=Title,Id

Comment: Thanks :) Will try it later

Comment: I tried Your REST API approach and it looks like it works nice. I am able to retrieve all items from library on the SharePoint. But is there any way to add some condition WHERE CaseID = "" ? The current REST url looks like this:  https://teams.test.sharepoint.com/cs/libraryName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('libraryTitle')/items/"

Comment: Please read document in my answer link which shows how to filter, select, orderby and lot more. Please mark my reply as answer.

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Thank You Milind. Your help was really usefull. This is what I did to filter some items based on CaseID https://teams.test.sharepoint.com/cs/libraryName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('libraryTitle')/items?$filter=CaseID eq '1234567'

Comment: It is correct way to do.

Comment: Could I ask about one more favor? I would like to update item status based on CaseID which i previously retrieve. Which methood of this REST API can be used?

Comment: Start Chat which will be faster

Comment: I would but dont know how use it yet :P sorry

Comment: You can update please read over here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: Please up vote too :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found they way how it should be done to perform update:

1. First we need to get item ID (like which one we want to update)
2. We need to get SharePoint Request Diguest Token from sharepoint context api
3. Later we need to use POST methood with MERGE like that:

   ```
   Dim updateURL, updateBody, requestUpdater, userName, userPassword

   Set requestUpdater = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

   userName = "login"
   userPassword = "password"

   requestURL = "https://share.point.site.url.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items(<ID>)"

   body = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListName' }, 'DescriptionField':'"& description &"' }"

   With requestUpdater
           .Open "POST", updateURL, False, userName, userPassword
           .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
           .setRequestHeader "X-RequestDigest", token
           .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
           .setRequestHeader "IF-MATCH", "*"
           .setRequestHeader "X-Http-Method", "MERGE"
           .send body
   End With
   ```

Its done in VB Script, but maybe someone will search for solution like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am already doing inside my VBS script:

Retriving item from library based on his CASE ID.

Option Explicit

```
Dim restOBJ, url, userName, password, domain

Set restOBJ = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

url = "https://teams.sharepoint.com/cs/TestPage/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestLibrary')/items?$filter=CaseID eq '1234567'

restOBJ.open "GET", url, False
restOBJ.send

Watch.setVariable "XMLResponse", restOBJ.responseText
```

Can You please tell me how to update item?

Comment: I would like to update this particular item with this Case ID to change their Status field.

Comment: So inside request which I get I have my item (file from library) and I would like to update item property <Task_x0020_Status> from "Open" to "Completed"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for now:

```
Dim restUPDATE, siteURL, restBODY

Set restUPDATE = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

siteURL = "http://site url/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID')" // url to to sharepoint list

// the metadata type of list from XML response
// Field Task_x0020_Status updated to 'Updated'
restBODY = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListName' }, 'Task_x0020_Status': 'Updated' }"

With restUPDATE
    .Open "POST", siteURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    .send restBODY
End With


Watch.setVariable "XMLResponse", oHttp.responseText "Updated correctly"
```

Not sure if its right yet, because lost access to machine when testing that. What do You think?

It will update all items from list?